# How to insert 8000 products into Magento 2.1.5 Database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, magento2

We have 8000 Mechanic products list of Data in Php Database that we shifting Php website to Magento 2.1.5 Ecommerce website. That how should i Insert in Magento Database with which fields are must. please provide me a valid solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your products are currently in a database - the best way is exporting them into a CSV, altering the format of the columns to match what Magento expects and importing them in through the Magento admin panel, I wouldn't even think about directly importing them into the DB - 8000 products isn't that many really.

Comment: Thanks for response, which is the product table for magento to insert is it catalog_entity table?

Comment: Don't insert them directly into the DB. Use the Magento Administration panel to import them correctly. If you need to ask which tables are involved, you don't know enough to do it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to: System --> Import --> Choose type of items --> Filled the input --> Select a file for import (csv).

Follow this [guide](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html)